# How integrate RapidMiner in a PHP web application?

Tags: java, php, rapidminer

I've got an implementation in RapidMiner that classifies questions according to Bloom's taxonomy. I need to consume the data produced by a web application developed in PHP and show the results in the interface of the web application.

So I'm wondering if it is possible that the application in PHP communicates with RapidMiner to process the data and show the results provided by RapidMiner in the interface.

I know RapidMiner is implemented in Java, and there is the option of using Java bridge to comunicate PHP and JAVA, but I'm not sure if that is a solution to this.

Comment: This is a general question like yours. Looks like the best solution was to wrap the program in web service. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307531/php-communicating-w-java-program

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to communicate with xml, for example, PHP app sends a list of questions via xml to rm, it then processes it and returns an xml feed. I think this'll likely be the easiest solution.. As far as performance, I can't say one way or the other if it's the best solution